# BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2405

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am new to Laravel and I am trying to create a basic blog in which users can like a post. However I am getting the following error:

> BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2405: Call to undefined
>   method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::likes()

Below is the code that is being used:

PostController.php

```
    class PostController extends Controller
{
    public function getIndex()
    {
        $posts = Post::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(2);
        return view('blog.index', ['posts' => $posts]);
    }

    public function getAdminIndex()
    {
       $posts = Post::all();
        return view('admin.index', ['posts' => $posts]);
    }

    public function getPost($id)
    {
        $post = Post::find($id);
        return view('blog.post', ['post' => $post]);
    }

    public function getLikePost($id)
    {
        $post = Post::find($id);
        $like = new Like();
        $post->likes()->save($like);
        return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

Post.php

```
<?php

namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['title', 'content'];

    public function likes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Like');
    }
}
```

Like.php

```
<?php

namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Like extends Model
{
    public function post()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Post');
    }
}
```

post.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('content')
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <p class="quote">{{ $post-> title}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <p>{{ count($post->likes) }} Likes | <a href="{{ route('blog.post.like', [ 'id' => $post->id ]) }}">Like</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <p>{{ $post->content }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

routes.php

```
Route::get('/', [
    'uses' => 'PostController@getIndex',
    'as' => 'blog.index'
]);

Route::get('post/{id}', [
    'uses' => 'PostController@getPost',
    'as' => 'blog.post'
]);

Route::get('post/{id}/like', [
    'uses' => 'PostController@getLikePost',
    'as' => 'blog.post.like'
]);

Route::get('about', function () {
    return view('other.about');
})->name('other.about');

Route::get('Register', function () {
    return view('auth.register');
})->name('auth.register');

Route::get('Login', function () {
    return view('auth.login');
})->name('auth.login');
```

I cannot see where the issue lies in the likes method nor in the controller. I am limited to Laravel 5.2 due to the limitations of Cloud 9 IDE.

Output of dd($post):

```
Post {#182 ▼
  #fillable: array:2 [▼
    0 => "title"
    1 => "content"
  ]
  #connection: null
  #table: null
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  #perPage: 15
  +incrementing: true
  +timestamps: true
  #attributes: array:5 [▼
    "id" => 1
    "created_at" => "2018-05-31 20:19:50"
    "updated_at" => "2018-05-31 20:19:50"
    "title" => "Another test"
    "content" => "adsasjioh919789172y"
  ]
  #original: array:5 [▼
    "id" => 1
    "created_at" => "2018-05-31 20:19:50"
    "updated_at" => "2018-05-31 20:19:50"
    "title" => "Another test"
    "content" => "adsasjioh919789172y"
  ]
  #relations: []
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #appends: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▼
    0 => "*"
  ]
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #casts: []
  #touches: []
  #observables: []
  #with: []
  #morphClass: null
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you are not trying to add like to non-existent post id?

Comment: Instead  of `$post->likes()->save($like);` try `$post->likes->save($like);`

Comment: The correct id is being passed as currently there is only 1 post that exists and the id is visible in the URL and it is referencing the correct id. 

I tried to run `$post->likes->save($like); ` however this gave a new error of `Call to a member function save() on a non-object` as it is not calling the likes method anymore.

Comment: Can you `dd($post)` right after you call `Post::find($id);`? Something seems very wrong with the result of that `find` call. Separately, can you also `dd($id)`?

Comment: @AlexHarris I have run those and I cannot see anything out the ordinary, I've added to output of dd($post) to the question, the dd($id) only returned value "1" which would be correct as that is the id of the post

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is your `likes` table fields are?

```
<?php

namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Like extends Model
{
     $fillable = ['post_id', 'user_id']; //YOU HAVE TO REPLACE THIS WITH YOUR FIELDS NAME
    public function post()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Post');
    }
}
```

Then your post Controller looks like below:

```
 class PostController extends Controller

     public function getLikePost($id)
     {
        $post = Post::find($id);
        $like = new Like(['user_id' => Auth::user()->id]);
        $post->likes()->save($like);

        return redirect()->back();
     }
 }
```

Comment: In the likes table I only have the following fields `id | created_at | updated_at | post_id`

Currently I do not have any users set up in the application and I am just trying to get a relationship set up between the posts and likes therefore that code did not work unfortunately.

Comment: If you have only post_id fields in that case you don't pass anything. `$like = new Like();` and rest code still stay same.

Answer (score 0):

After creating many to many relationships in the program the issue somehow resolved itself.

Wish I had more details but I do not know how this happened.

Many thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by creating many to many relationships in the program? As in share what code changed to resolve this issue.

Comment: I created a new migration in which I added a post-tag table allowing multiple tags to be assoiciated with multiple posts. I found an example on github and proceeded to follow their code and it somehow fixed the issue. The git link is [Laravel code](https://github.com/mschwarzmueller/pluralsight-laravel-getting-started/tree/09-relations)